# Confirming class instantiation with return value in function

Tags: python, function, class, python-2.7, instanceof

New to Python, so bear with me...

Given the following function (and assuming the class referenced here is created properly):

```
def next_scene(scene_name):
    print scene_name
    scenes = {'Chip_in_the_car': ChipCar(), 'Chip_in_the_studio': ChipInStudio(), 'Chip_mom_house': ChipMomHouse(), 'Chip_at_rehearsal': SickFuckingPuppies(), 'Death': Death()}

    for key, value in scenes.iteritems():
        if scene_name == key:
            print value
            return value
```

Ok, so what's returned here as `value` is the following:

```
<__main__.ChipCar object at 0x104503390>
```

Does that now mean that an instance of the `ChipCar` class has been instantiated or is it simply just returning the class as an object's place in memory? How can I use this function to create an instance of that `ChipCar` class?

Thanks for any insight (sure this is a noob question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have an instance of the class. You are looking at the default `__repr__` return value for instances, which includes the module name, the class name and the `id()` value of the object expressed as hexadecimal.

You can give your class a custom `__repr__` method to alter that text, it should return a string that is useful when debugging. For example:

```
>>> class ChipCar(object):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '{}() object, id => 0x{:x}'.format(type(self).__name__, id(self))
... 
>>> ChipCar()
ChipCar() object, id => 0x1046c33d0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What exactly is that hexadecimal representation? So that now means I can take `value` and use it as an instance of the `ChipCar` class, correct?

Comment: @Malvin9000: yes, your value is an instance of `ChipCar` and all methods that the class defines can be used. The `id()` value is a just a number that differentiates this instance from other objects. In the CPython (default) implementation of Python, that number happens to be the memory address, but other implementations can use different methods to generate the number. See the [`id()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).